# Cannot set text in textview in my custom tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am trying to load my UITextView on UItableViewCell with data but unable to set text. UITextViewDelegate is also set and attached to view controller. The text string is not empty as I checked it using debugger.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CommentCellIdentifier];
    //CommentCell is my custom cell with textView.
    CommentCell *commentsCell = (CommentCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CommentCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CommentCellIdentifier];
    }

    //Setting the images for all buttons in service row.
    [commentsCell.deletecomment setImage:deleteComment forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [commentsCell.editcomment setImage:editComment forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    commentsCell.deletecomment.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    commentsCell.editcomment.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
     NSInteger commentIndex = 2;

    //CommentsArray is NSArray with data.
    [commentCell.comments setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:commentIndex]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you registered that cell or added it in storyboard?
You should breakpoint inside your `if (cell == nil) { ..}` and see it's false

Comment: Better to use custom cell

Comment: Yes. I added it in storyboard and assign it my custom cell class. There is not  need of registration as I am doing same in my other view controllers. The only difference is that I am using UITextView instead of UIlabel.

Comment: Cell is registered and not false and I am using custom cell as you can see I am setting the images and they are setting properly.

Comment: 1) `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` can't return `nil`, so the following `if` statement is useless.  2) The `if` statement is buggy, anyway, because it creates a generic `UITableViewCell`.  Delete the `if` block.

Comment: Have you verified that `comments` is not `nil`?

Comment: First, check the text inside UITextView by `NSLog(@"Text: %@",textView.test);` 
If it returns your string, please check textColor, check autolayout if you are using autolayout to set dynamically height for cell

Comment: Yes, comments is not nil @Avi

Comment: check the textview, whether it is nil or not

Comment: TextView is null @James

Comment: textview is not initialize, check in the storyboard, to connect it to the IBoutlet of the textview

Comment: It is already connected. Is it necessary to initialize it [UITextView alloc]init because I used UILabels and there is not need of initialization. By nil means NSLog(@"Text: %@",textView.test);

Comment: I found the bug. commentsCell.editcomment.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;  [commentCell.comments setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:commentIndex]]]; I am using "commentCell" instead of "commentsCell". Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong cellname. Just replaced "commentCell" with "commentsCell" and everything starts working.

```
[commentsCell.comments setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[commentsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:commentIndex]]];`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CommentCellIdentifier];
```

to this line:

```
CommentCell *cell = (CommentCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CommentCellIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need scrolling the textview **DISABLE SCROLLING** in order for the text to appear.

I am not sure if this is caused by the fact that both the tableview and textview are descendants of UIScrollView, but it could be.

It helped me when I was experiencing the same issue